# How can I tell whether a .doc was created by LibreOffice?

Tags: ms-word, libreoffice, doc

I am looking at a programmatic/automated workaround for the LibreOffice/Word [compatibility bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=69343) that causes the last line of .doc files saved by LibreOffice to be cut off when viewing them in Word. Because of the volume of documents and the number of Word-only users, this may be easier than user education.

I have thousands of documents to work with, and while I can apply the "fix" to all of them, I'd prefer to limit it to just the documents that were saved by LibreOffice.

Is there metadata or other characteristic of the files that will (somewhat reliably) tell me whether the Word-format document was originally created by LibreOffice?

Comment: Have you considered converting all the documents to either `.docx` or `.odt`?  Those formats are easier to manipulate because they can be unzipped and modified as XML.

Comment: @JimK - Yes, and that actually is the fix I apply to the documents that have a problem—but since I am not the creator of the documents (they come from external sources) it would be nice to be able to run the batch operation on just the files that I can see need to be converted. Otherwise, I'm converting thousands that don't need it in order to catch the dozens that do!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/865856/300548) over at Superuser suggests a string search to determine which *version* of Microsoft Word has edited the file. So I had a look to see if there was anything else in there and found, near where the version string is, the string

`Microsoft Word-Dokument` - in LibreOffice .doc files

`Microsoft Word 97-2003 Document` - in Microsoft saved files.

Opening and resaving a LibreOffice .doc in Word, changes the string and vice versa. So this *may* be a solution for you.

There is still a question as to whether all versions of MS Office and Libre/OpenOffice use the same strings but at least it is a start.

How you search for it, I leave that up to you.